# TSLint: "expected arrow-call-signature to have a typedef", когда все типы аннотированы

Tags: typescript, типы, типизация

Не понимаю, какую ещё сигнатуру вызова TSLint хочет, когда я всё, что есть, аннотировал:

```
const removeFirstLineFromString: (multilineString: string) => string =
        (multilineString: string) => multilineString.substring(multilineString.indexOf('\n') + 1);

const removeLastLineFromString: (multilineString: string) => string =
        (multilineString: string) => multilineString.substring(multilineString.lastIndexOf('\n') + 1, -1);
```

Аналогично в случае:

```
const removeFirstLineFromString: (multilineString: string) => string =
    multilineString => multilineString.substring(multilineString.indexOf('\n') + 1);

const removeLastLineFromString: (multilineString: string) => string =
    multilineString => multilineString.substring(multilineString.lastIndexOf('\n') + 1, -1);
```

Comment: попробуйте указать возвращаемое значение функции `(multilineString: string): string => ...`, а не тип переменной `removeFirstLineFromString`

Comment: @overthesanity, Сработало! Всё-таки я не всё, что можно, аннотировал, как сказал об этом в вопросе. Нужно продублировать тип возвращаемого значения...